# JUnit, TestNg and Mockito Null Pointer Exception

Tags: junit, mockito, testng

The annotation @Spy and @Mock of org.mockito not working in my junit test class.

The code above throws a null pointer exception.

Eg:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class XServiceImplTest {

    @Spy
    private XServiceImpl xService;

    @Test
    public void testGenererPdf() throws Exception {
        xService.anyCall();
    }
}
```

When adding this code, the test works fine

```
    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation @Test that I was using was from testng package instead of Junit.

Changing that resolved my issue.